# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Main.ThrowCrossThreadMessageException

Tags: winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker, multithreading

I have created an Excel Add-In in Visual Studio 2008 for Excel 2003 that (among other things) clears object data from multiple excel sheets based on user selection.  The add-in runs as it should, however, at random intervals on various actions will cause Excel to crash.  The code below contains a windows form with a progress bar, background worker and open file dialog (ofd).  This exception gets thrown: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Main.ThrowCrossThreadMessageException` (in case it isn't obvious) during the `Main()` event at `this.progressbar1.Text`.  I have tried several different methods to resolve this problem and it may be reflected in this code snippet - perhaps someone could enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong and what - if any of the methods that have been added - may be unnecessary.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;
    using Microsoft.Win32;

    namespace WindowsFormApplication
    {
        public partial class Form3 : Form
        {
            private int highestPercentageReached = 0;
            private bool skipreadonly = true;
            public Form3()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(main));
                newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                newThread.Start();   
            }

        [STAThread]
            private void main()
            {
                if ((bool)Invoke(new ExcelSelectHandler(ExcelSelect)))
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Show));
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
                }
            } 

            private void Form3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == (Char)Keys.Escape)
                {
                    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                }
            }

        private delegate bool ExcelSelectHandler();
            private bool ExcelSelect()
            {

                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Hide));
                ofd.Title = "Excel Reset";
                ofd.Multiselect = true;
                ofd.FileName = "";
                ofd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlt;*.xltx;*.xlsb;*.xlsm;*.xltm";
                DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
                return result == DialogResult.OK;

            }

            private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                DataRemove(worker, e);

            }

            private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                MethodInvoker proginvoke = delegate
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                };
                progressBar1.BeginInvoke(proginvoke);
            }



            private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
                }
                else if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
                }
                else
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
                }
            }


            private void DataRemove(BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                    int k = ofd.FileNames.Length;
                    int l = 0;
                    Excel.Application eapp = ThisAddIn.xlApplication;
                    Excel.Workbook eawb = eapp.ActiveWorkbook;
                    Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
                    xlApp.Visible = false;
                    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
                    foreach (var filename in ofd.FileNames)
                    {
                        if (l < k)
                        {
                            if (filename != eawb.FullName)
                            {
                                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ofd.FileNames[l].ToString(), missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                                Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveSheet;

                                Excel.ListRows xlRows = (Excel.ListRows)xlWorksheet.ListObjects;
                                if (xlWorkbook.ReadOnly)
                                {
                                    if (skipreadonly)
                                    {
                                        xlWorkbook.Close(false, missing, missing);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Hide));
                                        if (MessageBox.Show("Excel document '" + ofd.SafeFileNames[l].ToString() + "' is either opened or marked read only and data will not removed from this file.  Do you want to ignore this file and continue removing data?", "Data Remover", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
                                        {
                                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Show));
                                            if (worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
                                            {
                                                worker.CancelAsync();
                                                xlWorkbook.Close(false, missing, missing);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Show));
                                            xlWorkbook.Close(false, missing, missing);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (xlRows.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Excel.ListRow xlRow in xlRows)
                                        {
                                            xlRow.Delete();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    xlWorkbook.Save();
                                    xlWorkbook.Close(true, missing, missing);

                                }
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRows);
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);
                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Excel.Worksheet exlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)eawb.ActiveSheet;
                                Excel.ListRows xlRows = (Excel.ListRows)exlWorksheet.ListObjects;
                                foreach (Excel.ListRow xlRow in xlRows)
                                {
                                    xlRow.Delete();
                                }
                            }
                            l += 1;
                        }

                        if (worker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int percentComplete = l / k * 100;
                            highestPercentageReached = percentComplete;
                            worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete);
                        }
                    }
                    xlApp.Quit();

                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```